# How many chaincodes can be initiated on single channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was unable to instantiate a new chaincode on existing channel.

Whenever I am instantiating the chaincode it is not completing the process it just stopped at the below step; it is not even giving any error.

```
2019-01-11 11:38:33.117 UTC [msp] Validate -> DEBU 035 MSP DEFAULT validating identity
2019-01-11 11:38:33.118 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 036 parsed scheme: ""
2019-01-11 11:38:33.119 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 037 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-01-11 11:38:33.119 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 038 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer:7051 0  <nil>}]
2019-01-11 11:38:33.119 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 039 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-01-11 11:38:33.120 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03a pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00049ecd0, CONNECTING
2019-01-11 11:38:33.122 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03b pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00049ecd0, READY
2019-01-11 11:38:33.122 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03c parsed scheme: ""
2019-01-11 11:38:33.123 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 03d scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-01-11 11:38:33.123 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03e ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{peer:7051 0  <nil>}]
2019-01-11 11:38:33.124 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03f ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-01-11 11:38:33.124 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 040 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0005031d0, CONNECTING
2019-01-11 11:38:33.125 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 041 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0005031d0, READY
2019-01-11 11:38:33.126 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 042 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-01-11 11:38:33.127 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 043 Sign: plaintext: 0AC3070A5B08011A0B08B980E2E10510...6967426C6F636B0A076D6172626C6550
2019-01-11 11:38:33.127 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 044 Sign: digest: C15AF406B7792459D13D2577F6E0EDD7399C78D9EA0BE381005FFF38D1A6EC68
```

What is the problem here?
how many chaincodes can be instantiate on a single channel?
If only one What is the reason?
Edited:
In fabric samples there are many chaincodes in go
so first I instantiated the sacc chaincode then I was trying to instantiating the marbles02 chaincode on the same channel but the chaincode name was different for both.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you provide an example where you try to install and instantiate the new chaincode?. In general you can install and instantiate different chaincodes on one channel but they need to differ in name of version.

Comment: I edited the question. So as per your comment It is possible to instantiate multiple chaincode on single channel, Am I correct?

Comment: You can install as many chaincode on one channel there is no problem in that. Just make sure you have different name for each chaincode. Please check logs on peer container you can definitely see the error there.